# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.DateTime.now()Lorg/joda/time/DateTime; on Webogic

Tags: weblogic, jodatime

Getting this during runtime on Weblogic 10:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.DateTime.now()Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;`

Joda-time 2.9.9

Comment: Well it's about a different method and if you search for this exception (with `now()`) you won't find the answer

Comment: Sure, the exact details which method is missing are different, but the underlying reason seems to be the same. Weblogic uses an outdated version of Joda, but you can adjust the weblogic deployment descriptor to use the jar-file of Joda in the lib directory instead of the weblogic joda. Just follow the link and look at the suggestion in the accepted answer.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I've marked it as duplicate